# Why isn't physical web enabled by default?

Tags: google-chrome, web, eddystone, eddystone-url

https://google.github.io/physical-web/try-physical-web
Here it explains how to enable it. 
Why isn't it enabled already? Are there plans to change it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a service like the Physical Web and not ask the user to opt in. It certainly slows down adoption but it's the right thing to do. In the long run, this will encourage more people to turn it on as it shows we respect users privacy.

Comment: Sorry but this his a strong limitation and the PW remains hidden for the folks. Nobody can enable what is unknown.

Comment: It is a strong but temporal limitation. That nobody is first 10% of anything, these people embrance new and unknown things, sometimes because of a micro moment, other times they're just out for a hunt.